# Exchanging german driver licence with UK license

Tags: united-kingdom

I have a german car license issued 2010 , now i live in UK since last decemmber.
I checked that getting car insurance is much cheaper with UK license.

So wanted to exchange german to british license

Will i get a issue date of british license from 2010 or will it be like a new one issue date 2015

best regards

Comment: That's weird, most insurance companies I've checked don't care if you have full EEA or full UK licence.

Comment: i changed from EU(german) to UK license and the quote i got was almost half